# Create update query from select sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I did a select query to find which products have a reference set when they not have a combination, and want to update that value to NULL from the result.

Anyone got an idea on how to build the query for the update?

SELECT QUERY:

```
SELECT 
  `id_product_supplier` , `id_product` , `id_product_attribute` ,
  `product_supplier_reference` , COUNT( `product_supplier_reference` )
FROM `ps_product_supplier`
GROUP BY `id_product`
HAVING COUNT( `product_supplier_reference` ) >1
AND `id_product_attribute` =0
AND `product_supplier_reference` >0
```

I want to have an update that is `product_supplier_reference` = NULL from the result.

Comment: MySQL or SQL-Server? Don't tag both

Comment: What update query have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry i deleted the sql-server tag, its in phpmyadmin i try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
update ps_product_supplier  tt inner join(
SELECT 
`id_product_supplier` , `id_product` , `id_product_attribute` , `product_supplier_reference` , COUNT( `product_supplier_reference` )
FROM `ps_product_supplier`
GROUP BY `id_product`
HAVING COUNT( `product_supplier_reference` ) >1
AND `id_product_attribute` =0
AND `product_supplier_reference` >0)t on t.id_product_supplier=tt.id_product_supplier
set tt.product_supplier_reference=null
```

Comment: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from ps_product_supplier t inner join( SELECT `id_product_supplier` , `id_pr' at line 2

Comment: No error but this instead: #1052 - Column 'product_supplier_reference' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: @TeddPersson consider upvoting/ accepting/ both this answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try below script 

 UPDATE ps_product_supplier SET product_supplier_reference = --Value
 FROM
 (
   SELECT  id_product_supplier , id_product , id_product_attribute ,   
   product_supplier_reference , COUNT( product_supplier_reference ) 
   FROM ps_product_supplier 
   GROUP BY id_product 
   HAVING COUNT( product_supplier_reference ) >1 AND id_product_attribute =0      
   AND product_supplier_reference >0
 ) A WHERE --Your Codition
```

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS** if you want to simply update the particular column then select only required column in select statement as below and join it for the update:

```
UPDATE `ps_product_supplier` pps
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 
          `id_product`
        FROM `ps_product_supplier`
        WHERE `id_product_attribute` =0
        AND `product_supplier_reference` >0
        GROUP BY `id_product`
        HAVING COUNT( `product_supplier_reference` ) >1) p ON p.id_product = pps.id_product
SET pps.product_supplier_reference = NULL
```